# Subfields of $\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt[n]{a}\bigr)$ for $a>0$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, alternative-proof

This is related to a [question on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316908/how-can-i-find-all-intermediate-fields-between-mathbbq-left-sqrtda-righ).

Given a rational number $a>0$ and an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x^n - a$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, it is known that every subfield of $\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt[n]{a}\bigr)$ has the form $\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt[d]{a}\bigr)$ for some $d\mid n$.

Is there an elementary proof of this result?  All of the references I could find use cogalois theory.  (See [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404986900678), for example, immediately after the proof of Theorem 1.6.)

Comment: What you claim "is known" is false (even if you impose the intended hypothesis that $X^n-a$ is irreducible over $\mathbf{Q}$). (No idea what "cogalois" theory is.) For $e \ge 3$ and a nonzero rational $h$, $X^{2^e}+h^2$ is irreducible yet the extension generated by one root contains $\mathbf{Q}(i, \sqrt{2h})$.  In general, if $X^n-a$ is irreducible over $\mathbf{Q}$ with $4|n$ and $a=-h^2$ then "extra" subfields always exist; the situation is especially thorny when $8|n$.  It is possible to determine all counterexamples. I have discovered a proof which this comment box is too small to contain.

Comment: @grghxy Note that $a>0$ in the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry for misreading.

Comment: @grghxy Good catch on the implied irreducibility hypothesis, though.  I've added it to the question.

Comment: Fix a subextension $F$, it must have degree $d$ dividing $n$. Then try to calculate the norm of $\sqrt[n]{a}$ to $F$. This element certainly lives in $F$ and it can be shown to be equal to $\pm \sqrt[d]{a}$ (the norm is the product over some galois conjugates, and you know them). Therefore you must have equality. You should fill the details, but I hope it is clear!

Answer (score 1):

Regular Galois theory is more than enough for this, see the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348621/radical-extension).